# SonarQube + Jenkins not producing Unit Tests Coverage

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have Jenkins v1.651.1 and SonarQube Runner 2.4 and SonarQube Server 4.5.2.

The Jenkins job runs `mvn clean test` to generate the `.exec` report. My analysis properties (part of the Jenkins build) look something like this:

```
sonar.sources=myproj

sonar.tests=myproj/runtime/src/test

sonar.language=java

sonar.java.test.binaries=myproj/runtime/target/test-classes
sonar.java.test.libraries=myproj/runtime/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
sonar.java.binaries=myproj/runtime/target/classes
sonar.java.libraries=myproj/runtime/target/admin/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar
sonar.java.source=1.8
sonar.java.coveragePlugin=jacoco

sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.jacoco.reportPath=myproj/target/jacoco.exec

sonar.junit.reportsPath=myproj/runtime/target/surefire-reports
```

The job completes successfully, but my Sonar dashboard looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU7G2.png) and the job can't find the class files:

```
02:35:52.170 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor...
02:35:52.171 INFO  - No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoItSensor done: 2 ms
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor...
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor done: 0 ms
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor...
02:35:52.172 INFO  - No JaCoCo analysis of project coverage can be done since there is no class files.
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor JaCoCoSensor done: 0 ms
02:35:52.172 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (wrapped)...
02:35:52.172 INFO  - JavaCpdEngine is used for java
```

***Before marking as duplicate, please note that I've tried to set `sonar.java.binaries`.***

I've also verified that the `.exec` file is there and when opening locally has the coverage values that I expect. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: As a general advice I would schedule an upgrade to SonarQube 5.6.4 LTS

Comment: +1 @JeroenHeier. Also @Josh, why are you doing a Maven build and a non-Maven analysis? Since you have a Maven-based project, `
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=[your SonarQube URL]` should "just work".

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam This command resulted in `Fail to connect to database: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: localhost"`. The jenkins sonar plugin is passing these properties correctly but somehow unable to get my class files, while the maven sonar plugin can't get the correct properties.

Comment: with a 'clean package' have you a report html generated in target dir ? first begin with this case. If no html report is generated, don't look for sonarqube now. Only when you have a jacoco html report in target dir, you can ask for sonarqube to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add this to your `pom.xml`?

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>report</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, this is in my `pom.xml`.